# Accuracy lost when using scipy.signal.lsim2

Tags: python, scipy, precision, numerical-integration, runge-kutta

I'm currently trying to implement a RK4 routine. In the process, I'm struggling to match accuracy order and found out that [`scipy.signal.lsim2()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lsim2.html) suffers from the same problem, even if using LSODA from ODEPACK (which should be even better than RK4).

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from scipy import signal
from sympy import meijerg, exp, lambdify, vectorize
from sympy.abc import t

# time and input
t0 = np.linspace(0, 0.5, 200+1)  # time vector
u0 = np.ones_like(t0)  # input vector (step)

# transfer function
sys = signal.TransferFunction([147.4, 2948.], [1., 162.14, 2948.])

# exact solution
expr_t = 147.4*meijerg(((-140.272532338765, -20.0, -19.8674676612354, 1), ()),
                     ((), (-141.272532338765, -20.8674676612354, -19.0, 0)),
                     exp(t))
expr_ft = lambdify(t, expr_t)
expr_vft = vectorize(0)(lambda t: float(expr_ft(t)))
y_exact = np.array(expr_vft(t0))

h = t0[1] - t0[0]
print "Time step: h =", h
print "h^4 =", h**4
print "h^5 =", h**5
tout, y1, x1 = signal.lsim(sys, u0, t0)
print "Max global error lsim :", max(abs(y_exact - y1))
print "Max local  error lsim :", max(abs((y_exact[1:] - y_exact[:-1]) - (y1[1:] - y1[:-1])))
tout, y2, x2 = signal.lsim2(sys, u0, t0)
print "Max global error lsim2:", max(abs(y_exact - y2))
print "Max local  error lsim2:", max(abs((y_exact[1:] - y_exact[:-1]) - (y2[1:] - y2[:-1])))
```

This will print:

```
Time step: h = 0.0025
h^4 = 3.90625e-11
h^5 = 9.765625e-14
Max global error lsim : 1.02140518266e-14
Max local  error lsim : 1.80966353014e-14
Max global error lsim2: 2.62325227174e-06
Max local  error lsim2: 5.13960676496e-06
```

Since RK4 is a 4th order solver and LSODA is running many more steps, shouldn't I get better accuracy?

For the sake of completeness, I also did it all with [`scipy.integrate.ode()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.html#scipy.integrate.ode), setting the integrator to "dopri5" (explicit (4)5th order Runge-Kutta Dormand-Prince):

```
def dy(t, y0, u0=1.):
    return np.dot(sys.A, y0)+np.dot(sys.B, np.atleast_1d(u0))
def fy(x, u0=1.):
    return np.dot(sys.C, x)+np.dot(sys.D, np.atleast_1d(u0))
ode3 = integrate.ode(dy)
ode3.set_integrator('dopri5').set_initial_value(np.r_[0.,0.])
x3 = np.zeros((len(t0), 2))
for i in range(1, len(t0)):
    x3[i] = ode3.integrate(t0[i])
y3 = np.squeeze(np.apply_along_axis(fy, 1, x3))
print "Max global error dopri5:", max(abs(y_exact - y3))
print "Max local  error dopri5:", max(abs((y_exact[1:] - y_exact[:-1]) - (y3[1:] - y3[:-1])))
```

Which prints:

```
Max global error dopri5: 2.36753650018e-08
Max local  error dopri5: 6.88440715546e-09
```

Finally, the question is: **is there any problem with `lsim2()` implementation or those error levels are expected?. Shouldn't errors be lower than `h^4 = 3.90625e-11`?** I have checked most of the code and couldn't find any problems. I have also compared with my hand-made RK4 function and it also gets Xe-06 errors. **Could it be some problem with my interpretation of O(h^5) and o(h^4) error notation?**

Comment: `lsim2` solves the system using `scipy.integrate.odeint`.  Additional keyword arguments given to `lsim2` are passed to `odeint`.  Try using lower error tolerances, e.g. `rtol=1e-10, atol=1e-12`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser, I did manually test `scipy.integrate.odeint`, just so I could use the `full_output=True` parameter. Using it, I found out with info['nqu'] that using `rtol=1e-10, atol=1e-12` increased the maximum method order from 5 to 8, and info['nst'] indicated that it went from 88 internal steps to 218. This means the computational cost is much higher, and shouldn't I achieve errors better than that for such small steps?